# How to deselect all controls in a form?

Tags: c#

I have dynamically created a list of buttons and set it to the form. After clicking one of them, the very next button to it will appear as selected.

Is it possible to deselect all controls dynamically created in a form? Particularly, can I, somehow, deselect that button after clicking the one before it?

```cs
private void GenerateButton()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 25; ++j)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Location = p;
                    button.Size = size;
                    button.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                    button.Padding = pad;
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
                    this.Controls.Add(button);
                    p.X += 23;
                }
                p.Y += 23;
                p.X = 0;
            }
        }

        protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button but = sender as Button;
            but.Enabled = false;
            but.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
```

Comment: It might be that you set the index of every button to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this method, which will select the next button in the form, after clicking on a button. You need to attach this button event handler to all your buttons. The order of buttons is determined by their order in the form Controls list. If you want a specific order, you will need to use LINQ to sort Controls by their TabOrder property and ensure your TabOrder is set properly

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = (Control)sender;

            btn.Enabled = false;
            btn.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

            // Where is this button in the form?
            var indexOfThisButton = this.Controls.IndexOf(btn);

            // Find next button index
            for (int i = indexOfThisButton+1; i < this.Controls.Count; i ++)
            {
                // If it's a button, select it
                if (this.Controls[i] is Button)
                {
                    this.Controls[i].Select();
                    return;
                }
            }

            // If we got down here we have got to the end of the controls list, start again
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                // If it's a button, select it
                if (this.Controls[i] is Button)
                {
                    this.Controls[i].Select();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have asked how to deselect instead of select it.

Comment: No, you wrote "After clicking one of them, the very next button to it will appear as selected." That's what my code does. After clicking the button, the next button will appear as selected. If you want to deselect the clicked button, what is wrong with your code? You want to deselect the button BEFORE the clicked button? Just track the last clicked button in button_Click() event handler.

Comment: I have wrote that the code is already selecting the next button, i don't know why. But you helped as I have managed to solve the problem. Thanks.